# Fadeout menu and switch it with Back to top button

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I'm looking for some help with some basic javascript. I have a fixed menu that fades out when I scroll down. At this point I would like to fade in a back top button, but my only problem is I can't get the back to top button to fade in and out like the menu does. It keeps flashing.

I've tried to use .stop() I'm not sure if this the right way to go about this.

Here's a link to my codepen — http://codepen.io/veryrobert/pen/xbEaH

HTML

```
<div>
  <button id="top">Back to top</button>
  <ul id="nav" >
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()>10;
  var top = $('#top');
  var nav = $('#nav');

  if(scrollTop != 0) {

  nav.fadeOut();  
  top.fadeIn();
  }

  else {
// I was missing my {} 
nav.fadeIn();  
top.fadeOut();
}   
});
```

I'm sorry if this is fairly simple but I just can't get my head around it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the `button` having a display of none.

```
#top { position:fixed; top:50px; display: none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fkdLE/

Also don't forget the `{}` on your else statement.

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var top = $('#top');
  var nav = $('#nav');
  if(scrollTop != 0) {
     nav.fadeOut();  
     top.fadeIn();
  }
  else{
     nav.fadeIn();  
     top.fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: Strange. I tried exactly that in CodePen and it wouldn't work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwszu

Comment: I see you also modified the JS. You should probably post that in your answer.

Comment: @isherwood It was because of the way he wrote his `else` statement. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/whxlL

Comment: Ah jaysus… I was missing my {} after the else…

Comment: I had that fixed and it still didn't work. You also have to remove the 'complete' argument as you've done here.

Comment: Sorry was just trying something after I posted it.